# Host web scraping (with selenium) python program on Heroku that runs every 5 hours

Tags: python, selenium, heroku

I created a python program that uses the selenium library to log in with my credentials to my school's website, press on some tabs to get to the grades screen, then saves the grades for each trimester in some text documents that he created.

I'd like this program to be executed every 5 hours on Heroku (or any free other platforms that would allow me to do so).

Here's the program:

```py
import os, time, re, datetime
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

url = "www.SchoolWebsite.com"

username = "myUsername"
password = "myPassword"

# Get the time and date of the data extraction
date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
date = date.replace(':', '--')[:21]
# Start Browser without showing it to the user
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=['--headless'], options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

# Wait until page is loaded
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_15"))) #"id_15" = connect button

# Enter Login Info
text_entry = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_23") #"id_23" = username entry
text_entry.send_keys(username)
text_entry = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_24") #"id_24" = password entry
text_entry.send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)

# Wait until page is loaded and open Grade Tab
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
gradesTab = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[0].Instances[1]_Combo2"))) #"GInterface.Instances[0].Instances[1]_Combo2" = Grades Tab
gradesTab.click()

time.sleep(1)
# Move mouse to X:0 Y:0
moveMouse = ActionChains(driver)
moveMouse.move_by_offset(0, 0).perform()

# extractData() is called to extract and organize the grades of each trimestre
def extractData():   
    # Decide whether Scrolling is needed or not:
    doScroll = True
    try:
        scrollbar_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1].ScrollV")
    except:
        doScroll = False
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    grades_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1]_zone_fils"))) #"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1]_zone_fils" = All Grades

    # If Scrolling is needed:
    if doScroll:
        scrollbar_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1].ScrollV")))
        final_location = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight;", scrollbar_element)

        # Choose the step of each scrolling
        def get_divisors(num):
            divisors = []
            for i in range(1, num + 1):
                if num % i == 0:
                    divisors.append(i)
            return divisors 
        step = max(filter(lambda x: x < 100, get_divisors(final_location)))

        # Get the last element's id:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight;", scrollbar_element)
        a=0
        while True:
            try:
                driver.find_element(By.ID, f"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1]_1_{a}")
            except:
                a=a+1
                continue
            while True:
                try:
                    driver.find_element(By.ID, f"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1]_1_{a}")
                except:
                    lastElement = a-1
                    break
                a=a+1
                continue
            break
        scrollbar_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1].ScrollV")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = 0;", scrollbar_element)

        # Save text available before Scrolling:
        htmlElement = grades_element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlElement, 'html.parser')
        grades = soup.get_text()
        all_grades = [grades]

        currElement=0
        r=0
        scroll = 0
        while currElement <= lastElement:    
            # 3.Check if more text is available
            currText = BeautifulSoup(driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1]_zone_fils").get_attribute("innerHTML"), 'html.parser').get_text()
            if currText == grades:
                # 3.1 If not scroll again
                pass 
            else:
                # 3.2 If more text is available then repeat the 3 steps
                grades = currText
                all_grades.append(grades)
                r=0
                currElement=currElement+1
                continue
            
            # 1.Find the next element that isn't available and needs more scrolling to be loaded:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, f"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1]_1_{currElement}")))
                currElement=currElement+1
            # 2.When found scroll 5 times, every time add the value of step
            except:
                for i in range(5):
                    scrollbar_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[1].ScrollV")
                    scroll = scroll + step
                    r=r+1
                    driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].scrollTop = {scroll};", scrollbar_element)
                continue

        # Combine all the extracted texts from the different points of the scroll bar:
        def longestSubstringFinder(string1, string2):
            answer = ""
            len1, len2 = len(string1), len(string2)
            for i in range(len1):
                match = ""
                for j in range(len2):
                    if (i + j < len1 and string1[i + j] == string2[j]):
                        match += string2[j]
                    else:
                        if (len(match) > len(answer)): answer = match
                        match = ""
            return answer

        for i in range(len(all_grades)-1):
            all_grades[i] = all_grades[i][:all_grades[i].index("Moyenne")]

        FullString = all_grades[0]
        for i in range(1, len(all_grades)):
            FullString = FullString + all_grades[i].replace(longestSubstringFinder(all_grades[i-1], all_grades[i]),'')
    # If no scrolling is needed:
    else:
        # Extract all the text:
        htmlElement = grades_element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlElement, 'html.parser')
        FullString = soup.get_text()

    print("FULLSTRING (156):", FullString)
    # Keep only the Subjects, Grades and Averages from the extracted data:
    FullString = FullString.replace(',', '.')
    FullString = FullString[2:]

    FullString = re.sub(r"   le \S{5}", "", FullString)
    FullString = re.sub(r"   Hier", "", FullString)
    FullString = re.sub(r"   Aujourd'hui", "", FullString)
    FullString = re.sub(r" Moy\. classe : \d+\.\d+/\d+", "", FullString)
    FullString = re.sub(r" Moy\. groupe : \d+\.\d+/\d+", "", FullString)
    FullString = re.sub(r" Moy\. classe : \d+\.\d+", "", FullString)
    FullString = re.sub(r" Moy\. groupe : \d+\.\d+", "", FullString)
    FullString = FullString[:FullString.index("Moyenne générale classe")-6]
    FullString = re.sub(r"Sujet Corrigé", "", FullString)
    FullString = FullString.replace(" ", " ") #replace character U+00a0 by space
    FullString = FullString.replace("Moyenne", " Moyenne")

    # Arrange the data in dictionaries:
    FullStringList = FullString.split(' ')
    words=['']
    numbers = ['']
    # A) Create a dictionary containing each subject and its average:
    # A.1) Differenciate Numbers from Words:
    for i in FullStringList:
        try:
            if ":" in i:
                pass
            elif "/" in i:
                numbers.append(i)
            elif "" == i:
                numbers.append(i)
                words.append(i)
            else:
                float(i)
                numbers.append(float(i))
        except:
            words.append(i)
    words.append('')
    words.append('END')
    # A.2) Create a list of all the subjects:
    subjects=[]
    for i in range(1, len(words)):
        if words[i] == "":
            subject = []
            for j in range(1,i+1):
                if words[i-j] != '':
                    subject.append(words[i-j])
                else:
                    break
            subject.reverse()
            subject = ' '.join(subject)
            subjects.append(subject)

    # A.3) Create a list of all the averages:
    averages=[]
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] == "":
            averages.append(numbers[i+1])
    
    def list2dict(keys_list, values_list):
        result = {}
        for key in keys_list:
            for value in values_list:
                result[key] = value
                values_list.remove(value)
                break 
        return result

    # A.4) Create the dictionary:
    subjAverages = list2dict(subjects,averages)

    # B) Create a dictionary containing each subject and its grades:
    # B.1) Remove the averages from numbers to only get a list of all the grades:
    grades=[]
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        try:
            float(numbers[i])
            numbers[i] = str(numbers[i]) + '/20'
        except:
            pass
        if numbers[i] == "":
            grades.append(numbers[i])
        elif numbers[i-1] == "":
            pass
        else:
            grades.append(numbers[i])

    # B.2) Create a list containing one list for every subject's grades:
    sortedGrades = []
    for i in range(len(grades)-1):
        if grades[i] == '':
            tempList = []
            for j in range(i+1, len(grades)):
                if grades[j] != '':
                    tempList.append(grades[j])
                else:
                    break
            sortedGrades.append(tempList)

    # B.3) Create the dictionary:
    subjGrades = list2dict(subjects, sortedGrades)

    return [subjAverages, subjGrades]

# Open Trimestre Selector and press on Trimestre 1
driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_wrapperbouton").click() #"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_wrapperbouton" = Trimestre Selector
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_0").click() #"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_0" = Trimestre 1 in Trimestre Selector
time.sleep(1)
# Check if there is any grade posted in Trimestre 1:
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_137"))) #"id_137" = No grades message
    if "Il n'y a pas de notes pour la période sélectionnée."in driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_137").text:
        # Don't extract Trimestre 1 data, there isn't any
        Trimestre1 = "There are no grades for the selected period."
    else:
        # Extract Trimestre 1 data
        Trimestre1 = extractData()
except:
    # Extract Trimestre 1 data
    Trimestre1 = extractData()

# Open Trimestre Selector and press on Trimestre 2
driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_wrapperbouton").click() #"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_wrapperbouton" = Trimestre Selector
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_1").click() #"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_1" = Trimestre 2 in Trimestre Selector
time.sleep(1)
# Check if there is any grade posted in Trimestre 2:
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_137"))) #"id_137" = No grades message
    if "Il n'y a pas de notes pour la période sélectionnée."in driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_137").text:
        # Don't extract Trimestre 2 data, there isn't any
        Trimestre2 = "There are no grades for the selected period."
    else:
        # Extract Trimestre 2 data
        Trimestre2 = extractData()
except:
    # Extract Trimestre 2 data
    Trimestre2 = extractData()

# Open Trimestre Selector and press on Trimestre 3
driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_wrapperbouton").click() #"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_wrapperbouton" = Trimestre Selector
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_2").click() #"GInterface.Instances[2].Instances[0]_2" = Trimestre 3 in Trimestre Selector
time.sleep(1)
# Check if there is any grade posted in Trimestre 3:
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_137"))) #"id_137" = No grades message
    if "Il n'y a pas de notes pour la période sélectionnée." in driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_137").text:
        # Don't extract Trimestre 3 data, there isn't any
        Trimestre3 = "There are no grades for the selected period."
    else:
        # Extract Trimestre 3 data
        Trimestre3 = extractData()
except:
    # Extract Trimestre 3 data
    Trimestre3 = extractData()

f=open(os.path.abspath(f"Data Extraction\\{date}.txt"), 'w', encoding='utf-8')
date = date.replace("--", ":")
print(f"{date}\n\nTrimester1 = {Trimestre1}\n\nTrimester2 = {Trimestre2}\n\nTrimester3 = {Trimestre3}", file=f)
f.close()
driver.close()
```

Comment: did you check out : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python

Comment: You told us what you want, but haven't actually asked a question. What part of the problem do you need help with?

Comment: @BryanOakley my problem is that I can’t have my pc turned on non stop but I just need it to run it once every 2 hours, how could I do so with heroku?

Comment: Maybe you should work through some training material on  how to use heroku. It sounds like what you're asking can be answered by existing documentation.